# Thread Finished Event in Python

Tags: python, delegates, multithreading

I have a PyQt program, in this program I start a new thread for drawing a complicated image.
I want to know when the thread has finished so I can print the image on the form.

The only obstacle I'm facing is that I need to invoke the method of drawing from inside the GUI thread, so I want a way to tell the GUI thread to do something from inside the drawing thread.

I could do it using one thread but the program halts.

I used to do it in C# using a BackgroundWorker which had an event for finishing.

Is there a way to do such thing in Python? or should I hack into the main loop of PyQt application and change it a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the samples with [PyQt-Py2.6-gpl-4.4.4-2.exe](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download), there's the Mandelbrot app.  In my install, the source is in C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\examples\threads\mandelbrot.pyw.  It uses a thread to render the pixmap and a signal (search the code for QtCore.SIGNAL) to tell the GUI thread its time to draw.  Looks like what you want.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with one of my projects, and used signals to tell my main GUI thread when to display results from the worker and update a progress bar.

Note that there are several examples to connect objects and signals in the [PyQt reference guide](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/pyqt4ref.html#signal-and-slot-support). Not all of which apply to python (took me a while to realize this).

Here are the examples you want to look at for connecting a python signal to a python function.

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(a, QtCore.SIGNAL("PySig"), pyFunction)
a.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("pySig"), "Hello", "World")
```

Also, don't forget to add `__pyqtSignals__ = ( "PySig", )` to your worker class.

Here's a stripped down version of what I did:

```
class MyGui(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.worker = None

    def makeWorker(self):
        #create new thread
        self.worker = Worker(work_to_do)
        #connect thread to GUI function
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.worker, QtCore.SIGNAL('progressUpdated'), self.updateWorkerProgress)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.worker, QtCore.SIGNAL('resultsReady'), self.updateResults)
        #start thread
        self.worker.start()

    def updateResults(self):
        results = self.worker.results
        #display results in the GUI

    def updateWorkerProgress(self, msg)
        progress = self.worker.progress
        #update progress bar and display msg in status bar


class Worker(QtCore.QThread):

    __pyqtSignals__ = ( "resultsReady", 
                        "progressUpdated" )

    def __init__(self, work_queue):
        self.progress = 0  
        self.results = []
        self.work_queue = work_queue
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, None)

    def run(self):
        #do whatever work
        num_work_items = len(self.work_queue)
        for i, work_item in enumerate(self.work_queue):
            new_progress = int((float(i)/num_work_items)*100)
            #emit signal only if progress has changed
            if self.progress != new_progress:
                self.progress = new_progress
                self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("progressUpdated"), 'Working...')
            #process work item and update results
            result = processWorkItem(work_item)
            self.results.append(result)
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("resultsReady"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your drawing thread can send an event to the main thread using QApplication.postEvent. You just need to pick some object as the receiver of the event. [More info](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Jeff's answer: the [Qt documentation on thread support](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/threads.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads) states that it's possible to make event handlers (slots in Qt parlance) execute in the thread that "owns" an object.

So in your case, you'd define a slot printImage(QImage) on the form, and a doneDrawing(QImage) signal on whatever is creating the image, and just connect them using a queued or auto connection.