# Python PyQt4 signal not firing connected method

Tags: python, multithreading, signals, pyqt4

I decided to use signals to indicate the completion of a thread. I wired the signal to code that restarts the process if more work still exists. Alas, the code connected to the signal never fires. This makes me sad.

I need to know why the method 'Tester' in the code block below doesn't fire.

I'm new to python so when I started writing this I researched signals and modelled the code after a solution that [tgray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64206/tgray) posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812870/thread-finished-event-in-python) and apparently I missed something important, but I seriously just can't see what it is.

Here is a massively simplified version of my code:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import time

class Worker(QThread):
    __pyqtSignals__ = ( "a", 
                        "b" )
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self, None)


    def run(self):
        print "'Worker.run' starts"
        self.emit(SIGNAL("a"))
        print "'Worker.run' ends"


class Main:
    def Do(self):
        print "'Do' starts"
        self.Launch()
        time.sleep(2)
        print "'Do' ends"


    def Launch(self):
        print "'Launch' starts"
        self.worker = Worker()
        QObject.connect(self.worker, SIGNAL("a"), self.Tester)
        self.worker.daemon = True
        self.worker.start()
        print "'Launch' ends"


    def Tester(self):
        print "Tester Fired!!"

m=Main()
```

Running:

```
>>> m.Do()
```

Yields:

```
'Do' starts
'Launch' starts
'Launch' ends
'Do' ends
'Worker.run' starts
'Worker.run' ends
```

But not the expected:

```
Tester Fired!!
```

What did I miss? Also, why do the prints in "Worker.run" appear after everything else even with the `sleep(2)`?

Comment: Note that, instead of using `QObject.connect(...)` you could us the [new-style signal and slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html): `self.worker.a.connect(self.Tester)`. This has various advantages: It is easier to read, it is shorter, and it is safer, because if the `a` signal doesn't exist an error will be raised, while with the other method the connection would have failed silently.

Comment: Good point! I will def refactor to implement the new-style s&s as soon as I get this version functional. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see your callback being called, you have to change the way you connect
your QThread signal to your slot:

```
 QtCore.QObject.connect(self.worker,
                        Qt.SIGNAL("a"),
                        self.Tester,
                        Qt.Qt.DirectConnection) #this is added
```

**Explanation:**
Qt signals/slots are thread safe since Qt 4. Documentation says the normal behaviour when
connecting a signal to a slot is 'AutoConnection', which means it is direct (callback is
fired immediately after emit) if both signal and slot are in the same thread, whereas it
is queued if the signal is emitted from another thread (your case).

Then, something has to process this queue: normally, this is done by the Qt loop while your application is running.

The fact that a signal is "queued" means control is transferred to the Qt loop, to make
sure the callback is called in the main thread even if the signal comes from another
thread.

In your question's code, there is no event loop at all - so the only way of getting your
slots called from another thread is to change the way signals are dispatched. Don't use
that in your code, though, since in a normal application you have the Qt loop running,
it would have been dispatched properly (and safely from threading issues).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes I see now that my implementation was fundamentally flawed ( no QT loop, sigh ). I'm hoping to put enough practice and study time into Python, PySide and PyGame to reach a profession programmer level understanding of the mechanics. Then I can help others and create good code. I've found that python info on things like this falls into 2 groups: extremely basic examples, or advanced user docs that assume deep knowledge of the base framework. So I'm trying to slog my way through the middle ground til I reach a 'critical mass' of knowledge on the subject. Thanks again!